# No output file when gulp uncss inside usemin

Tags: javascript, gulp

This is my simplified task

```
gulp.task("compile", ["inject"], function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.Build.index)
    .pipe(usemin({
      css: [uncss({html: htmlFileList})]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.BuildRoot));
});
```

When I try to use uncss inside usemin, there is not style.css output. The same task work perfcly without uncss ( i tried minifycss for example ) .

My htmlFileList is an array of html files and if i use uncss in a separate task with my compiled style.css (after my compile task) or a with a list of css, it works too.

Any idea how to use uncss inside usemin ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? Could you try using this instead? https://github.com/futurechan/gulp-asset-transform